# Simulating a deadlock on a thread

Tags: python, process, deadlock

I have 3 threads, that are currently running simultaneously.

```
def f1():
    print "running first thread\n"
    sleep(10)

def f2():
    print "running second thread\n"
    sleep(10)

def f3():
    print "running third thread\n"
    sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread1 = Thread(target = f1)
    thread2 = Thread(target = f2)
    thread3 = Thread(target = f3)

    try:
        thread1 = Thread(target = f1)
        thread1.start()

        thread2 = Thread(target = f2)
        thread2.start()

        thread3 = Thread(target = f3)   
        thread3.start()

        while(thread1.isAlive() or thread2.isAlive() or thread3.isAlive()): 
            thread1.join()
            thread2.join()
            thread3.join()  
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sys.exit()
```

How can I simulate a deadlock? Also, how can I have each thread run after the other? Also can I list all the threads that are currently running in my script? or give them priorities ?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a deadlock (as the title asks), or actually create a deadlock (as the body asks)? And, if the latter, do you just want a trivial artificial case of deadlock that would never arise in real life, or the simplest example of a somewhat realistic scenario?

Comment: For starters, you might want to have a lock that you can deadlock on somewhere: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

Comment: @abarnert; I actually need to simulate a deadlock, sorry ill edit my post.

Comment: @paulsm4: Well, you can use the threads themselves. For example, just do `thread2.join()` in `f1` and `thread1.join()` in `f2`, and that will deadlock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I simulate a deadlock?

All a deadlock means is that one or more threads are blocked from making any progress, so you can simulate it with a single thread. Just put a `while True:` around the `sleep(10)`.

In realistic cases, you usually have two threads blocking each other from progress at the same time. For example, maybe they've taken a pair of locks in reverse order, so thread 1 won't release lock 1 until it gets lock 2, but thread 2 won't release lock 2 until it gets lock 1. So, it might be better to simulate it by having two threads block permanently.

If you want to actually create a deadlock, the simplest way is to have the threads literally block on each other: add `thread2.join()` to `f1`, and `thread1.join()` to `f2`. Then `f1` can't finish until `f2` does, `f2` can't finish until `f1` does, so neither one can ever finish.

However, if you want to create a realistic deadlock, you will almost certainly want to use synchronization objects like [`threading.Lock`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) to do something like the two-lock scenario described above.

> Also, how can I have each thread run after the other?

Well, the easy way would be to not use threads in the first place. But if you really want, just do this:

```
thread1.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.start()
thread2.join()
thread3.start()
thread3.join()
```

> Also can I list all the threads that are currently running in my script?

See [threading.enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate). You usually don't want to use this except for debugging purposes; keep track of the threads as you create them, if you want to have access to them later (as you're doing).

> or give them priorities ?

As the docs say:

> currently, there are no priorities, no thread groups, and threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted.

If you want this, you have to step outside of `threading` and, e.g., use native APIs via `ctypes`, `win32api`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**How can I simulate a deadlock?**

```
import threading
import time

l1=threading.Lock()
l2 = threading.Lock()

def f1(name):
    print('thread',name,'about to lock l1')
    with l1:
        print('thread',name,'has lock l1')
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print('thread',name,'about to lock l2')
        with l2:
            print('thread',name,'run into deadLock,\nthis line will never run')

def f2(name):
    print('thread',name,'about to lock l2')
    with l2:
        print('thread',name,'has lock l2')
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print('thread',name,'about to lock l1')
        with l1:
            print('thread',name,'run into deadLock,\nthis line will never run')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1=threading.Thread(target=f1, args=['t1',])
    t2=threading.Thread(target=f2, args=['t2',])

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

*output:*

```
$ python tmpThread.py
thread t1 about to lock l1
thread t2 about to lock l2
thread t1 has lock l1
thread t2 has lock l2
thread t1 about to lock l2
thread t2 about to lock l1
```

Comment: Good answer but there's typo in function f2's second 'with'
it must be 'with l1'

Answer (score 0):

Classical bank transfer deadlock example.

```
from threading import Lock, Thread

accountone = Lock()
accounttwo = Lock()

def transfer(accountone, accounttwo):
    accountone.acquire()
    accounttwo.acquire()
    print("Transaction done")
    accountone.release()
    accounttwo.release()

def transfer_do(accountone, accounttwo):
    while True:
        transfer(accountone, accounttwo) # send money from first account to second
        transfer(accounttwo, accountone) # send money from second account to first

for x in range(30):
    t = Thread(target=transfer_do, args=(accountone, accounttwo))
    t.start()
```